# Button position can't be placed correctly

Tags: android

I am developing an android app but buttons can't be placed correct position. I use `layout_width="match_parent"` but it is going to the right side. `layout_gravity= "center"` is also same.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="368dp"
android:layout_height="495dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        />

    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_spotify"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        fancy:fb_textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="#FFFFFF"
        fancy:fb_iconResource="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
        fancy:fb_defaultColor="#6495ED"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="#9bd823"

        fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
        fancy:fb_radius="10dp"
        fancy:fb_text="LOAD PICTURE"
        fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ru.dimorinny.floatingtextbutton.FloatingTextButton
        android:id="@+id/action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:floating_background_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:floating_icon="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
        app:floating_title="Load Picture"
        app:floating_title_color="@android:color/white" />


    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PROCESS"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:id="@+id/btn_process"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_process"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next Page"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_process"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NO TEXT"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:id="@+id/textview_result"
        />


    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

So how can I fix it? I want to place the button correct position & it will be same for all android phone.

Comment: Please mention or attach an image how do you want your buttons to be placed which would provide us a better insight of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the width of Main parent layout `Linearlayout` width to `Match_Parent` and remove  `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"` and  `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"`

Edit :

As this `LinearLayout` is under `ConstraintLayout`. You need to assign `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf` and
           `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf` property.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: I used match_parent but it is automatically replaced by 368dp.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving a fixed height and width for your parent LinearLayout. Either try

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

or go with a relativelayout.

Comment: I used match_parent but it is automatically replaced by 368dp

Answer (score 0):

Set Parent Linear layout width to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

```
<LinearLayout 
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_spotify"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="#FFFFFF"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
        fancy:fb_defaultColor="#6495ED"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="#9bd823"
        fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
        fancy:fb_iconResource="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"

        fancy:fb_radius="10dp"
        fancy:fb_text="LOAD PICTURE"
        fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fancy:fb_textSize="20dp" />

    <ru.dimorinny.floatingtextbutton.FloatingTextButton
        android:id="@+id/action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:floating_background_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:floating_icon="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
        app:floating_title="Load Picture"
        app:floating_title_color="@android:color/white" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_process"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:text="PROCESS" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_process"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:text="Next Page" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_process"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:text="NO TEXT"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you using `ConstraintLayout` as parent?

Comment: Yes. And I can fix it :)

Comment: show us your code properly this is not the right way you should ask if you cann't than we cann't give proper answers. questions on Stackoverflow better read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

if your LinearLayout is under **ConstraintLayout** use this

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```